# swap letters with numeric , using javascript search

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, a self-learner using free pdf books, google and Stackoverflow.
I am stuck in a self assigned task ...

Swapping words with numeric digits, taking values from one text-box, performing swapping and putting result in another text-box. For example when I type six svn zro the output must be 670

But when I type something in textBox1 the result in textbox2 is "Undefined"**

Please debug it only using simple JavaScript, not jQuery.

Here is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
 {
    var a = ["one","two","tri","for","fiv","six","svn","egt","nin","zro"];
    var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
    var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("textBox2").value;
    var len = str.length;  

       for (var k=0; k < 200; k++)  
          {
            var n = str.search(new RegExp(a[k], "i"));
            var str1 = str.substring(0, n) + b[k] + str.substring(n+3, len);
            document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str1.toString();
          };
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text"  onkeyup="myFunction();" id="textBox1" autofocus/>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="text"   id="textBox2" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add in what exactly isn't working at the moment? Then we can help you better. One simple thing I can see is that your for loop goes up to 200 but array `a` only has 10 items in it, so `a[k]` will cause problems. `k < a.length` can fix that, if that is what you need

Comment: For 0 to 9 I would recommend having  `var a = ["zro","one","two","tri","for","fiv","six","svn","egt","nin"];` since a[digit] would return the string needed

Comment: thanx Rhumborl i got that a.lenth thing, but the problem is when i type something in textBox1 the result in textBox2 is "undefined"

Comment: What is the expected input and the expected output?

Comment: when i type    six svn zro    the out must be    670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get `undefined` is still because of the `for` loop.

When `k` reaches `10`, `a[10]` does not exist and so returns `undefined`. This gets used as the replacement value in your string.

If you restrict `k` to the length of array `a`, you will not get undefined values.

The other issue is that you are always starting from the original string, so previous replacements are ignored. You need to always use `str` and not have `str1`.

Finally it is simpler to just use the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function rather than working out substrings - I tried to reuse your substring code but couldn't get it working.

So your function can become:

```js
function myFunction() {
    // values to search for - these can be strings or a regex string
    var a = ["zro", "one", "two", "tri", "for", "fiv", "six", "svn", "egt", "nin"];

    // get the input value
    // we will perform all replacements against this
    var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value;

    // loop through the array and replace each value in "str" with its index
    // note we are reusing "str" each time to keep the previous replacements intact
    // replace() can take either a string or a regex
    for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        // put "zro" at the start of "a" so "k" is now the same as b[k] - no need for "b"
        // create a RegExp from the string, set it to global replace (g) so it works if there is more than one match in the string, and case insensitive (i) in case they type "One"
        str = str.replace(new RegExp(a[k], "gi"), k);
    };

    // store final value in the other textbox
    document.getElementById('textBox2').value = str;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction();" id="textBox1" autofocus="autofocus" />
<br/>
<input type="text" id="textBox2" />
```

**EDIT/footnote**: `replace()` is still simpler but you *can* use `substring()` - the problem with your original code is that if the regex does not match anything, `n` will be -1 and mess up `str`. So you need to check if `n > -1` before you do the substring part:

```
for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
    var n = str.search(new RegExp(a[k], "i"));
    if(n > -1) {
        // n+a[k].length is better than n+3, in case a[k] isn't 3 chars!
        str = str.substring(0, n) + k + str.substring(n+a[k].length, str.length);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanx man  , but here is a problem with your code , when i type 'six six' (two times six) it retuns '6 six' as a result

Comment: you need to use a regex with a global (g) flag. I have updated the answer to use this

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = ["zro","one","two","tri","for","fiv","six","svn","egt","nin"]; // 0-based 
  var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value; 
  var words = str.split(" "),len=words.length, str1=""; // split on words
  for (var i=0; i < len; i++) { // run over length of array
    var idx = a.indexOf(words[i]); // find the word in the index array
    if (idx !=-1) str1+=idx;
  }
  if (str1) document.getElementById('textBox2').value=str1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction();" id="textBox1" autofocus/>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<input type="text"   id="textBox2" />
```

If you want to have any entry containing any of the a[] strings, then this will do it

```
function myFunction1() {
  var str = document.getElementById("textBox1").value; 
  var a = ["zro","one","two","tri","for","fiv","six","svn","egt","nin"];
  var len = a.length;
  for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
    var idx = str.indexOf(a[i]); // or str.toUpperCase().indexOf(a[i].toUpperCase()) 
    if (idx !=-1) str = str.split(a[i]).join(i); // or use substr if case insensitive
  }
  if (str) document.getElementById('textBox2').value=str;
 }
```

Comment: thanx mplungjan , but when i type oone ( glued with o) it returns nothing

Comment: But that is not in your use case so I am not handling it. "trick" should then return 3ck - not understandable according to your specification - see update for that version